# Why the packages subfig, babel-slovene and TikZ don't like each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, babel

Consider the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \usepackage[english,slovene]{babel}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[labelsep=space,
                labelfont={sf,bf},
                textfont=sf,
                justification=RaggedRight,
                caption=false]{subfig}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes,
% added for compatibility with babel ...
                babel
                }
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}
\tikzset{
MA/.style args = {#1/#2}{% My Angle label position!
    draw, <->,
    angle radius=#1,
    angle eccentricity=#2},
every pic quotes/.append style = {inner sep=1pt, anchor=west},
        }
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \subfloat[\label{fig:1.39a}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%---
\draw[->]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B);
\draw[->]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,33mm);
%---
\draw[thick,->]
    (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
    (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
\pic [MA=11mm/1.1,"$\omega_c t+\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
%----------------
\end{tikzpicture}
}
   \subfloat[\label{fig:1.39br}]%
{
%%%%    ht-138b (bandpass signal)
\begin{tikzpicture}
%---
\draw[->]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B);
\draw[->]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,33mm);
%---
\draw[thick,->]
    (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
    (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
\pic [MA=12mm/1.15,"$\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
%----------------
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As it is, it gives the well known error

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
```

Under some circumstances, when I don't use `\subfloat[...]{...}`, it seems that the TikZ library `babel` is able to manage the problem of quotes; however, in presence of `\subfloat` this is not a case any more.

How to convince those packages to work together?

**Addendum:**
meanwhile I got two answers. For my current works is more interesting ansfer of @egreg. Both his suggestion works for above MWE, however, real document is more complicated and suggested patch fails.

A MWE, which is more close to my real documents, is below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}

    \usepackage[english,slovene]{babel}
    \usepackage[labelsep=space, labelfont={sf,bf},
                textfont=sf,
                format=hang,
                justification=RaggedRight,
                caption=false]{subfig}

    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,arrows.meta,
                quotes,
                babel% for compatibility with babel ...
                    }

 \tikzset{SDVpsp/.style = {%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------%%
LA/.style args = {##1/##2}{%
        line width=##1,
        draw=##2,%color
        arrows={-Straight Barb[]}
                        },
%%-------------------------------------------------------------%%
LC/.style args = {##1/##2}{%
        line width=##1,
        draw=##2%color
        },
%%-------------------------------------------------------------%%
MA/.style args = {##1/##2}{% My Angle label position
    draw, <->,
    angle radius=##1,
    angle eccentricity=##2},
%%-------------------------------------------------------------%%
every pic quotes/.append style = {%
    inner sep=2pt, anchor=west},
%%-------------------------------------------------------------%%
                          }% end of styles
         }% end of tikzset
\newcommand\ce{\mathsf{ce}}         

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter% <--- sugested by egreg
\patchcmd{\sf@@@subfloat}{#4}{\scantokens{#4\empty}}{}{}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}      
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
%    \shorthandoff{"}% <--- suggested by egreg
\begin{sidecaption}{}%Fourier transform of $x_{1,pe}(f)$ and $x_{2,pe}(f)$}[fig:1.39]
\centering
    \subfloat[Phasor representation of $A\exp^{j2\pi f_c t+\varphi}$ \label{fig:1.39a}]
{
%%%%    ht-138a (bandpass signal)
\begin{tikzpicture}[SDVpsp,
    LA/.default = 0.3pt/gray,
                    ]
%---
\draw[LA]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B)
                                 node[below left] {$\Re$};
\draw[LA]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,44mm) node[below left] {$\Im$};
%---
\draw[LA=1pt/red]
    (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
    (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
\pic [MA=11mm/1,"$\omega_c t+\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
%----------------
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfill
    \subfloat[Complex envelope as a (slowly) varying amplitude and phase \label{fig:1.39b}]
{
%%%%    ht-138b (bandpass signal)
\begin{tikzpicture}[SDVpsp,
    LA/.default = 0.3pt/gray,
MA/.style args = {#1/#2}{% My Angle label position!
    draw, <->,
    angle radius=#1,
    angle eccentricity=#2},
every pic quotes/.append style = {inner sep=1pt, anchor=west},
                    ]
%---
\draw[LA]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B)
                                 node[below left] {$x_c$};
\draw[LA]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,44mm) node[below left] {$x_s$};
%---
\draw[LC=0.5pt/gray,densely dashed]
    (75:38mm) .. controls + (0.0,-0.3) and + (-0.3,0.3) ..
    (60:33mm) .. controls + (0.3,-0.3) and + (0.0,+0.3) ..
    (45:30mm) node[above right] {$x_\ce(t)$};
%---
\draw[LA=1pt/red]
    (0,0)       coordinate (O) -- node[above,sloped] {$A(t)$}
    (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
\pic [MA=12mm/1.15,"$\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
%----------------
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{sidecaption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I observe:

- patch with only one `#` gives error `!Parameters must be numbered consecutively`. This error I manage to cure with use of two `#`, i.e. with 
  `\patchcmd{\sf@@@subfloat}{##4}{\scantokens{##4\empty}}{}{}`
- unfortunately this patch doesn't help
- use of `\shorthandoff{"}` solve the problem with quotes, however it had to be add to each figure (if I understand correctly egreg answer) ... so I'm very interested, if it is possible to developed a patch, which will works as desired.

Comment: I think that `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\shorthandoff{"}}` should work (requires `etoolbox`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `babel` TikZ library solves the problem of the `"` shorthand by changing its category code when `tikzpicture` begins. However, when the `tikzpicture` is in the argument to `\subfloat`, this category code cannot be changed.

Solutions: use `subcaption` or patch `\subfloat` to do `\scantokens`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[english,slovene]{babel}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[
  labelsep=space,
  labelfont={sf,bf},
  textfont=sf,
  justification=RaggedRight,
  caption=false
]{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\sf@@@subfloat}{#4}{\scantokens{#4\empty}}{}{}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  angles,
  quotes,
  babel
}


\tikzset{
  MA/.style args = {#1/#2}{% My Angle label position!
    draw, <->,
    angle radius=#1,
    angle eccentricity=#2},
  every pic quotes/.append style = {inner sep=1pt, anchor=west},
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:1.39a}]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  %---
  \draw[->]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B);
  \draw[->]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,33mm);
  %---
  \draw[thick,->]
    (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
    (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
  \pic [MA=11mm/1.1,"$\omega_c t+\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
  %----------------
  \end{tikzpicture}
}\quad
\subfloat[\label{fig:1.39br}]{%
  %%%%    ht-138b (bandpass signal)
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  %---
  \draw[->]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B);
  \draw[->]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,33mm);
  %---
  \draw[thick,->]
    (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
    (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
  \pic [MA=12mm/1.15,"$\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
  %----------------
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Xyz}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution work fine in MWE, however in real document I receive error: `Parameters must be numbered consequently <to be read again> ##`. I need more time to figured-out the circumstances of this error.

Comment: @Zarko I can only think to a `#` character inside a `tikzpicture`. An alternative, if you don't need the shorthand in captions, is to say `\shorthandoff{"}` after `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a case. For real pictures I use `\tikzset{...}`, where I have defined parameters, which value is determined in picture (as color of nodes, lines, and similar). Even use \shorthandoff{"} doesn't help. before error `!Too many }'s` is mentioned `librarybabel.code.tex`. Compilation stop with error `Output loop--- 100 consecutive dead cycles`

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, but without an example it's difficult to say.

Comment: I managed to add in my question a MWE, which is more close to my real documents and exhibits mentioned troubles.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the newer package [`subcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package instead of `subfig`, and replace `\subfloat{...}` with the `subfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[english,slovene]{babel}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[labelsep=space,
            labelfont={sf,bf},
            textfont=sf,
            justification=RaggedRight]{subcaption}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  angles,
  quotes,
% added for compatibility with babel ...
  babel
}
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}
\tikzset{
  MA/.style args = {#1/#2}{% My Angle label position!
    draw, <->,
    angle radius=#1,
    angle eccentricity=#2},
  every pic quotes/.append style = {inner sep=1pt, anchor=west},
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % ---
      \draw[->]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B);
      \draw[->]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,33mm);
      % ---
      \draw[thick,->]
      (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
      (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
      \pic [MA=11mm/1.1,"$\omega_c t+\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
      % ----------------
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:1.39a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    %%%% ht-138b (bandpass signal)
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % ---
      \draw[->]   (-1mm,0) -- (44mm,0) coordinate (B);
      \draw[->]   (0,-1mm) -- (0,33mm);
      % ---
      \draw[thick,->]
      (0,0)       coordinate (O) --
      (60:33mm)   coordinate (A);
      \pic [MA=12mm/1.15,"$\varphi$",red] {angle = B--O--A};
      % ----------------
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:1.39br}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing of package I can consider in new LaTeX project, in existing ones require to much work (few hundreds images ...).